# Magento 2.3 Message only has text/html MIME parts

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, order-email

In mail-tester there is a suggestion to ad `text/plain` to my new order email. How to do that? Is there a way to combine html format with `text/plain`?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No, unfortunatly